# Can you increase max_allowed_packet from the client?

Tags: mysql, windows-7, mysql-5.5

I need to execute a SQL dump with very large extended inserts. I'm using the [official command-line tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html) in my computer to connect to a server in the LAN. The execution always dies:

> ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away

... and I'm fairly sure that it's due to a tiny `max_allowed_packet` setting:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+----------+
| Variable_name      | Value    |
+--------------------+----------+
| max_allowed_packet | 10485760 |
+--------------------+----------+
```

There're lots of documentation on how to change the setting **in the server** but I wonder if it's possible to change it just for current connection, i.e., **from the client** side. I don't need a general solution, I'll be happy if it works for the command line tool.

I've checked documentation and [found this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_max_allowed_packet):

> `max_allowed_packet`
>
> The maximum packet length to send to or receive from the server. (Default value is 16MB.)

... and subsequently tried this:

```
mysql ^
    --max_allowed_packet=50M ^
    --compress ^
    --default-character-set=utf8 ^
    --skip-reconnect ^
    -h mysql.example.com -u foo -b bar
```

Result: all commands to read `max_allowed_packet` still report 10MB and server still goes away.

Can you increase `max_allowed_packet` from the client side?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/418814/how-to-increase-mysql-max-allowed-packet-for-client

Comment: @SomnathMuluk - Thanks for the link, my question is basically a dupe of that. The answer is not very clear but suggests it's a privileges problem. I'll test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've read many articles that explain how to accomplish this but I've reached the conclusion that they simply haven't tested it properly. My conclusions are:

- Server's `max_allowed_packet` is a hard-coded upper limit. You can change it for the whole server as any other server-side setting (configuration file or server command-line parameters) but it isn't possible to increase it from the client.
- Some clients (such as the official command line utility) allow to set `max_allowed_packet` on connection. It's the only way to actually change the value from a client (changing session or global variables has no effect on the size of exchanged packages) but it's only useful if you want to *lower* it. Sending packages larger than the server's setting will still trigger package related errors since the server will not accept them.

To sum up:

1. You have to treat `max_allowed_packet` as read-only.
2. If it's too small, you need to change it for the whole server or live with it.

*It's a pity that I cannot provide links to official documentation but this subject is poorly documented.*