# MySql: dump BLOB into local file

Tags: mysql, shell

how do i dump the contents of a blob to a file? the thing is that the resulting file should be stored on a client and not on the server, and the solution should be handled in a shell script.

```
SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE/DUMPFILE ...
```

will fail because this would save the file directly on the server, not on the client.

```
echo "USE my_db; SELECT my_blob FROM my_table LIMIT 1" | mysql --<connection params> > $OUTFILE
```

writes garbled data into the local $OUTFILE, i guess including some formatting.

is there a way to disbale all formatting, or how can i get a 1:1 dump to a file?

any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with the [MySQL client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html) as long as you use the proper options.

In particular you should use [double-silent mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_silent) to suppress table formatting and the column name, and use [raw mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_raw) so no characters are escaped.

Here's an update of the command you tried that should get you on the right track:

```
mysql --<connection params> \
my_db \
--raw \
--silent \
--silent \
--execute \
"SELECT my_blob FROM my_table LIMIT 1" > $OUTFILE
```

Comment: thanks! however, this works perfectly for any column in my table, but on the blob column the result is empty, as if silent mode disables output of binary data... i should maybe note that the application in question is still using mysql 4.x

Comment: Is the blob value NULL in that row? Maybe try `SELECT my_blob FROM my_table WHERE my_blob IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1`

Comment: there is only 1 row in this table. i added your whereclause, but as expected this doesn't change anything... selecting a different column works, selecting the blob column returns nothing, or to be more precise it returns 1 byte (0A, LF).

Comment: maybe some more info, although i don't think this will change anything: the blob column is actually a LONGBLOB, and the contents of this column is ~144MB

Comment: In that case you may need to increase your max_allowed_packet setting to something larger than 144 MB.

Comment: good point, but no help... i had already added --max_allowed_packet=512M, because i got a packet error without this param. but in general, it IS possible to write a LONGBLOB 1:1 to a file, is it?

Comment: Have you increased `max_allowed_packet` on the server itself? I believe that [changing in from the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417371/can-you-increase-max-allowed-packet-from-the-client) is only useful to *lower* it.

Comment: yes, i have also tried with higher setting on the server (512M), same result, it doesn't help.

Comment: i replaced the content of the LONGBLOB with a small jpeg image, now i get "????" as result (4 characters), does this help anybody? using --raw --silent --silent

Comment: found a solution, using a php script to select the blob and write it to a file. i had to remove the first 12 bytes of the content i got from the database (comparing the original file and the file i got out of the db), so far this does the job, although i don't know what those 12 bytes are used for.

Answer (score 1):

I had to extract all files out of a table and came up with a simple bash script based on previous answer.

It's not very smart, but it does the job :)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

myUser=user
myPass=secret
myHost=localhost
myDb=database

myCmd="mysql -u$myUser -p$myPass -h$myHost -D$myDb"

$myCmd -e "SELECT id, file_name FROM files;" |
        while read id file_name; do
                echo $id $file_name;
                $myCmd --raw --silent --silent -e "SELECT file_data FROM files WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1;" > "$file_name"
        done;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html

> If the table contains more than one row, you must also use LIMIT 1 to limit the output to a single row.

Run all output rows of this

```sql
SELECT CONCAT("SELECT blob INTO DUMPFILE '", @@secure_file_priv, filename_field, "' FROM table WHERE filename_field = ", filename_field, " LIMIT 1;") FROM table
```

as sql, then find all the dumped files under the configured path of [`secure_file_priv`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) that defaults to `/var/lib/mysql-files/`